# Make vertical distance smaller for narrow screen

Tags: css

I'm building a page using [Infima](https://facebookincubator.github.io/infima/).

When the screen is large, the current layout is OK: `abc` and `def` are on the right side of the textarea, and I want the row of `abc` and the row of `def` to have some distance between them. I realize it by `<br/><br/><br/><br/>`.

When the screen is narrow, the position of `abc` is OK (i.e., just under the textarea). However, I want `def` to be **just below** `abc`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.10studio.tech/css/infima.default.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col--12">
          <div class="row align-items-end">
            <div class="col col--7">
              <textarea rows="10" cols="50">
              </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col col--3">
              abc
              <br/><br/><br/><br/>
              def
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) to change the layout of the page depending on the screen size. In this case you can do something like

```css
.verticalspace {
   height: 20px;
}

/* On screens that are 996px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 996px) {
  .verticalspace {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.10studio.tech/css/infima.default.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col--12">
          <div class="row align-items-end">
            <div class="col col--7">
              <textarea rows="10" cols="50">
              </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col col--3">
              abc
              <div class="verticalspace"></div>
              def
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your code works as expected? I still see vertical space for narrow screen.

Comment: Try playing around with the screen size of "600px" depends on the screen size you're looking at. Might want to increase it.

Comment: I see... is it possible to not hard-code `600px`? I want this to respect exactly the position of the block of `abc` and `def`: some vertical space when they are on the right of the textarea and no vertical space when they are below...

Comment: You'll have to follow the media queries in that external stylesheet (infima.default.css) you're using so you can mimic the responsive behavior defined in there. You'll see media queries that you can reuse so your behavior matches the other styles on the page.

Comment: that css file is not minimised, can you take a look and provide a complete answer?

Comment: Looks like they're using `996px` as the break point. Try that `@media (max-width: 996px)`?